# Flow of facebook login

Tags: facebook, jsp, facebook-graph-api, servlets

In my index page, I have this link for me to auth with the facebook.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://xxx.herokuapp.com/test">Test</a>
```

Inside my TestServlet, it will auth and get the access token for me to query the graph api. I will query and store the info into a list of 200 results. The results are forward to my jsp page (test.jsp).

Inside my test.jsp:

URL will show `http://xxx.herokuapp.com/test?code=xxx`

As I don't wish to display all 200 results at the same time, I only load 20 results at a time. I have a link to the next page `<a href='/test?page=${page+1}&code=${code}'>Next Page</a>` where the page is the current page number 1 and code is the code on the url.

However, I will hit this error when I clicked the 'Next Page' link:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://xxx.herokuapp.com/test&client_secret=xxx&code=xxx
```

Does the problem lies in encoding issue? If so, how should I encode the code in the url  and where should I encode it? Inside my jsp page or servlet? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get access_token again using the same "code" in your "next page" link. And Facebook is returning 400 bad request error. The "code" returned by facebook is supposed to be used just once to get the access_token. And once you have access token, use that for all further Graph API calls.

If you are using sessions, you can store the access_token in session and use that for Graph API calls. Otherwise, you can pass the access_token (instead of code) in the next page link:

```
<a href='/test?page=${page+1}&access_token=${access_token}'>Next Page</a>
```

Comment: Ouch, I always thought the code is what I need to make further queries. I used your way and it worked. I have changed to session too as I don't really like to have a long string appearing in the url, thanks!